# Catching Null values in java

Tags: java, eclipse, null

```
    if (cached != null) 
    return cached.doubleValue();
```

When i am using these is java, first line is saying "The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) double, null". And 2nd line is saying "Cannot invoke `doubleValue()` on the primitive type double". How can i solve those two problems?

Comment: What is the type of `cached`?

Comment: @johnchen902 seems to be double

Comment: By paying attention to the compiler. Clearly `cached` is a primitive `double`. So you can't compare it to `null`, and you can't call methods on it. Either wrap it or restructure your code so the checks aren't needed. Perhaps you used a lowercase `double` when you wanted an uppercase `Double`.

Comment: It is allready a `double`. `return cached` is enough if you would return a double value.

Comment: @ZerO I know it *is* double. However I think OP should check it himself.

Answer (score 0):

Because `cached` is a primitive `double` change it to `Double`. If you want to continue to use  primitive's no need to check for `null` they by default are initialized to 0.0

Comment: One of the downvoting trolls seem to be awake.

Comment: If cached is a double then it can't be null - changing it to a Double does not seem very useful...

Comment: @assylias That's what the answer was isn't? Either change to `Double` if there a use case else no need to check for `null`

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of `cached` from `double` (primitive) to `Double` (class):

```
Double cached=null;
//do something with cached
if (cached != null) {
    return cached; //implicit unboxing, call to doubleValue() isn't needed
}
```

Since `double` is a primitive type, it can never assume the value null, moreover it does not have a method `.doubleValue()` defined.

Comment: +1 No reason to downvote.

Comment: If cached is a double then it can't be null - changing it to a Double does not seem very useful...

Comment: @assylias yes you're right, it can't be null as I wrote in the answer. I thought that maybe in the OP scenario there are some situation where the value of the variable may be set to null in order to signal a 'special case': if the variable isn't null, then return it normally, otherwise manage the situation in some way (maybe do another different computation for the value of cached)